# Display both levels of binary outcome in getDescriptionStatsBy

Tags: r

```
ex1 = sample(50, x=c("A","B"), replace=TRUE)
ex2 = sample(50, x=c("A","B"), replace=TRUE)
getDescriptionStatsBy(factor(ex1),ex2,html=TRUE,useNA="no",statistics=TRUE,add_total_col="last”)
```

with useNA=“no” or useNA=“ifany", I get

```
   A            B            Total        P-value
A  "13 (59.1%)" "16 (57.1%)" "29 (58.0%)" "1.0”
```

but with useNA=“always”, I get

```
        A            B            Total        P-value    
A       "13 (59.1%)" "16 (57.1%)" "29 (58.0%)" "1.0"  
B       "9 (40.9%)"  "12 (42.9%)" "21 (42.0%)" ""     
Missing "0 (0.0%)"   "0 (0.0%)"   "0 (0.0%)"   “"
```

Is there a way to force the display of both levels of the binary outcome (A and B) with useNA=“ifany”?  Although it is obvious to me that if there is no missing data, one must only show the row of “A” (and infer that B = 1-A), some of my colleagues seem to prefer that “A” and “B” are displayed always.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to answer my own question by using a wrapper function that removes the "Missing" row with useNA="always"

```
k2 = getDescriptionStatsBy(factor(ex1),ex2,html=TRUE,useNA="always",statistics=TRUE,add_total_col=FALSE)

r = table(ex2)
n0 = apply(k2,1,function(x) sum(x=="0 (0%)" | x=="0 (0.0%)"))
rmv = which(rownames(k2)=="Missing" & n0==length(r))
k2[-as.numeric(rmv),]
```

Note in the above, I set add_total_col=FALSE and consequently looked for n0==length(r); if add_total_col="last", I would look for n0==(length(r)+1)